# Как перенести файлы приложения на другое устройство?

Tags: java, android

Приложение в процессе работы создает файлы, которые надо перенести на другое устройство. Например множество настроек в определенном формате или картинки.

Идеально было бы сохранить на SD в отдельную папку, подключить к компьютеру и перенести на SD другого устройства. Но в версиях выше Android 5 сохранить в открытую папку на SD не получается.
Как быть? Какие варианты?

Делаю так:

```
private boolean accessSDwrite(){
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private boolean accessSDread(){
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if (accessSDread() & accessSDwrite()){
        dirSD = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM),"MyDir");
        if (!dirSD.mkdirs()) { Log.d(TAG, "dirSD: dir not create"); }
```

Comment: По сети не вариант?

Comment: А есть пример,как это реализовать? Я правильно понял: закачать файл на сервер и потом скачать?

Comment: Да, всё верно, посмотрите библиотеку retrofit.

Comment: можно попробовать Firebase

Comment: Почему не получается, какие ошибки? Что-то не так делаете видимо

Comment: в вопросе написал как я пробовал. Лог выводится "dir not create". Если будут идеи почему не работает, буду рад, а то не хочется через Firebase.